# PasswordChecker in Java

Tags: java, input, character

This is a class assignment and I have to check a user inputted password. I can't seem to figure out how to check the password for valid characters. These are the requirements:

1.Loop until a valid password has been entered.

A valid password:

should have at least 1 uppercase letter.

should have at least 1 lowercase letter.

should be at least 6 characters long.

should have at least 1 digit.

should only contain letters, digits or underscore

I need some help with the if statement that sets hasValidCharacters to true and setting the isValid to true so that I can display the correct password.

```
     String password;
     boolean isValid = false;
     boolean hasUpperCase = false;
     boolean hasLowerCase = false;
     boolean hasDigit = false;
     boolean hasValidCharacters = false;
     boolean hasLength = false;

     //Loop until a valid password is entered
     System.out.print("Enter password: ");
     password = kb.nextLine();
     char ch;
     for(int i=0;i<password.length();i++)
     {
       ch = password.charAt(i);

        //Display all appropriate error messages
        if(Character.isUpperCase(ch))
          hasUpperCase=true;
        else  
          System.out.println("ERROR:  should have at least 1 uppercase letter.");
        if(Character.isLowerCase(ch))
          hasLowerCase=true;
        else    
          System.out.println("ERROR: should have at least 1 lowercase letter.");
        if(password.length()>6)
          hasLength=true;
        else  
          System.out.println("ERROR: should be at least 6 characters long.");
        if(Character.isDigit(ch))  
          hasDigit=true;
        else  
          System.out.println("ERROR: should have at least 1 digit.");
        if()
          hasValidCharacters=true;
        else  
          System.out.println("ERROR: should only contain letters, digits or underscore");



        //Display password when valid   
        if(isValid=true)
          System.out.println(password + " is valid. ");
        else
          System.out.print("Enter valid password: ");
          password = kb.nextLine();  

     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. Don't want to spoon-feed, so here are my observations.

- Setup boolean variables for each "condition" (looks like you've already done this)
- You can call `password.length()` outside the loop just once (you're doing this each iteration)
- Remove the print statements from within the loop. Remember this loop will run X times (where X is length), and theoretically each character should only satisfy one condition. This means it will print all other `else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest wrapping your logic in a "do while" loop so that you can prompt the user again to enter his/her password while the password is not valid. Otherwise, your program will terminate and have to be re-run each time the user provides an non-qualifying password.

```
boolean valid = false;

do{
  //ask user for input

  //validate the input

}while(!valid);
```